# Using a function that requires a vector inside apply()

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I am trying to use the `dmultinom` function on every column of this matrix (below). Because I want to compute trinomial probabilities, I thought I could use apply on every column and use `dmultinom(,prob=c(1,2,3))` as FUN inside it. However that doesn't work.

```
apply(data,1,dmultinom(,prob = c(1,2,3)))

Error in dmultinom(,prob = c(1,2,3)) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

I think I could use a for loop to go trough every column and use that to compute the probabilities, but I think there should be a way to solve it using apply?

This is my data:

```
  V1.Freq V2.Freq V3.Freq V4.Freq V5.Freq V6.Freq V7.Freq V8.Freq V9.Freq V10.Freq
1      31      31      31      31      31      31      31      31      31       31
2     152     152     152     152     152     152     152     152     152      152
3      21      21      21      21      21      21      21      21      21       21
```

Comment: You can also read `help(apply)` for how to use `apply()`.  There are examples of usage at the bottom, executable in the console with `example(apply)`.  Same goes for most help files.

Comment: See `?apply` :: `...` : optional arguments to `FUN`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
apply(data,2,dmultinom,prob=c(1,2,3))
```

Note: `apply(data,1,..)` is row-wise

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find the proper syntax to use it, but I knew there had to be a way to use a simple function inside apply!